# mongoexport csv output last array values

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv, export

Inspired by this question in Server Fault
https://serverfault.com/questions/459042/mongoexport-csv-output-array-values

I'm using mongoexport to export some collections into CSV files, however when I try to target fields which are the **last** members of an array I cannot get it to export correctly.

Command I'm using

```
mongoexport -d db -c collection -fieldFile fields.txt --csv > out.csv
```

One item of my collection:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example",
    "date": [
        {"date": ""},
        {"date": ""},
    ],
    "status": [
         "true",
         "false",
    ],
}
```

I can access to the **first** member of my array writing the fields like the following

```
name
id
date.0.date
status.0
```

Is there a way to acess the **last** item of my array without knowing the lenght of the array?

Because the following doesn't work:

```
name
id
date.-1.date
status.-1
```

Any idea of the correct notation? Or if it's simply not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to reference the last element of the array without knowing the length of the array, since the notation is `array_field.index` where the index is in [0, length - 1]. You could use the aggregation framework to create the view of the data that you want to export, save it temporarily into a collection with $out, and then mongoexport that. For example, for your documents you could do

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$date" },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "date" : { "$last" : "$date" } } },
    { "$out" : "temp-for-csv" }
])
```

in order to get just the last date for each document and output it to the collection temp-for-csv.

You can return just the last elements in an array with the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection operator, but this isn't available in aggregation and mongoexport only takes a query specification, not a projection specification, since the `--fields` and `--fieldFile` option are supposed to suffice. Might be a good feature request to ask for using a query with a projection for mongoexport.

Comment: Thanks for this answer yep that might be a good fetature to request because I wanted to avoid scripting more juste using the fields should be usefull by itself